# jquery validator plugin field name with special characters

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Does anyone know how to get jQuery's validator plugin to recognize input field names with special characters?

I have a framework that is generating a form field with these characters: [].  Example:

`<input type="text" name="user[firstname]" id="user-firstname" />`

When using Jorn's plugin, the field is disregarded.

`rules: { user[firstname]: "required"}`
is not recognized.

But, if I remove the [] from the field name and change the requirement accordingly, no problem.

Anyone know how to escape the square brackets?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this `rules: { "user[firstname]": "required"}`

Comment: RafH: You're right.  I had a stupid typo in my script.  Works like a charm.  Thanks much!